# executeQuery not returning result for Hive

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, teradata, executequery

I am trying to export data from Hive to Teradata. Below is the code I have for the same:

```
/* Code Start */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class HiveToTd {
private final static String tdUser = "**********";
private final static String tdPass = "**********";

private final static String hiveUser = "**********";
private final static String hivePass = "**********";

private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // Get the Teradata connection 
    Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
    Connection tdcon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:teradata://database.XXXXX.com/TMODE=ANSI,TYPE=FASTLOAD", tdUser, tdPass);
    System.out.println("Connected to Teradata.");
    
    // Get our hive connection
    Class.forName(driverName);
    System.out.println("Connecting to Hive.");
    Connection hivecon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://bigdatabase.xxxxxx.com:10000/default", hiveUser, hivePass);
    System.out.println("Connected to Hive.");
    
    // Select our table from Hive
    
    Statement hst = hivecon.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Executing Statement");
    ResultSet hrs = hst.executeQuery("SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM db.table limit 100");
    
    System.out.println("Get DATA");
    int count= 0;
    if(hrs.next())
    {
        count++;
    }
  System.out.println(count);
```

The count is returned "1" and not 100. I have verified that I have more than 1 million records in the tables in Hive. What am I doing wrong? It just returns me the header row and that's it. I would have assumed the issue to be with the connection but then it gives me the right header row. So it has to be something else.

### Update

So looks like the code is actually working. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot Thusitha.

The next part is more troubling. This is for Fast Load to TD.

```
// Empty the staging table
    tdcon.createStatement().executeUpdate("delete from dbname.staging_table");

    // Create prepared statement for Teradata
    System.out.println("Begin load to Teradata");
    tdcon.setAutoCommit(false);
    
    PreparedStatement ps = tdcon.prepareStatement("insert into dbname.staging_table values (?,?,?)");
    System.out.println("Start Fastload");
    int i;
    for (i = 1; hrs.next(); i++){
        ps.setString(1, hrs.getString(1));
        ps.setString(2, hrs.getString(2));
        ps.setString(3, hrs.getString(3));
        ps.addBatch();
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i % 10000 == 0){
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    if (i % 10000 != 0){
        ps.executeBatch();
    }
    
    
    
    tdcon.commit();
    tdcon.setAutoCommit(true);
    ps.close();
    hrs.close();
    
    sideLoad("dbname.staging_table", "dbname.final_table", tdcon);
    tdcon.close();
    hivecon.close();
    
}

public static int sideLoad(String fromTable, String toTable, Connection conn) throws SQLException{
    return (conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + toTable + " SELECT * FROM " + fromTable));
    
}



}
```

The error I get after "start Fastload" message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 1103] [SQLState HY000] Cannot add an empty batch of rows to a database table
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:94)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:64)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2049)
    at com.optus.insights.HiveToTd.main(HiveToTd.java:84)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a `if` condition
so count it will only go to the first row of the ResultSet and increment count 1

If you want to iterate through all the rows use `while loop` instead of `if`
changes your code as follows

```
while(hrs.next()){
    count++;
}
```

Comment: However, when I am debugging the code, the resultset shows no rows fetched

Comment: Directly execute your query and check if you get data

Comment: while(hrs.next()){
    System.out.println(hrs.getString(1));
}
and check what you get

Comment: So it is reading the data. I think I should post the next part where I am trying to do a fastload